# SQL Server bcp command to csv file

Tags: sql-server, csv, bcp

We are using the SQL Server `bcp` command to export data to `.csv` file with the option `-t ,`. It works for some tables, but there are some columns that have comma in content, and the exported data are not correct. According to csv definition, if the content has comma in itself, it should be surround by double quotes.

For example, the content

```
hello,world,
```

should be exported as

```
"hello,world"
```

But `bcp` doesn't do that - how to resolve this issue?

Thanks,
Eric

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this for just a few tables/queries, you can escape those strings from a query. Like say you have a field `x` in a table `y`, you query would be:

```
SELECT '"'+REPLACE(x,'"','""')+'"' FROM y
```

There are no options in `bcp` (or `sqlcmd`) to automatically do this for you.